# Getting a IndexMissingException using tire w/ elasticsearch even after indexing model

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

When trying to run a query like:

```
search = Tire::Search::Search.new("retailer")
search.query { string('description:'+store) }
results = search.results.to_ary
```

I get the error: 404 : {"error":"IndexMissingException[[retailer] missing]","status":404}

I have indexed the model using Retailer.import in the console (which worked for the other model I indexed). This actually worked for my Retailer model initially, then soon after it started spitting out this error instead. I've also tried

1. `Retailer.index.import Retailer.all`, which returned "ArgumentError: wrong number of   arguments (0 for 1)"
2. and the rake task `rake tire:import CLASS=Retailer FORCE=true`, which returned "rake aborted! uninitialized constant Retailer"

My Retailer model looks like:

```
class Retailer
  include Mongoid::Document

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  mapping do
        indexes :id, :index => :not_analyzed
        indexes :description,  :analyzer => 'snowball'
  end

  field :description, :type => String
  field :logo_url, :type => String
  field :url, :type => String
  field :shopzilla_id, :type => String

  index :description => 1

  has_many :items
  embeds_many :scrape_urls

  validates :description, :presence => true

  def to_indexed_json
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :description => self.description
    }.to_json
  end


... end
```

Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use quotes: `rake tire:import CLASS='Retailer' FORCE=true`

Comment: That returns the same thing as without quotes, "rake aborted! uninitialized constant Retailer", unfortunately.

Comment: And if you use `rake environment tire:import CLASS='Retailer' FORCE=true`?

Comment: That works and indexed the class, however I still get the IndexMissingException for the retailer class.

Comment: Can you try to move the tire section (two includes and the mapping block) below field declarations?

    field :description, :type => String
    field :logo_url, :type => String
    field :url, :type => String
    field :shopzilla_id, :type => String
    
    index :description => 1
    
    include Tire::Model::Search
    include Tire::Model::Callbacks
    
    mapping do
      indexes :id, :index => :not_analyzed
      indexes :description,  :analyzer => 'snowball'
    end